# Can I create a list of images in my Google Drive (including file name and share link)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-drive-api

I have folders with several hundred images on Google Drive. I want to generate a spreadsheet by folder of the file name and also it's shareable link so that I can create a CSV file for bulk linking elsewhere.

I can bulk copy the shareable links, not with code, but by selecting all files in Google Drive, right clicking and using the share function. This produces a list of links that can be copy & pasted to a spreadsheet. However, I can't match them with file names.

I have found a script (below) to export a list of names and direct links (not share links), but can't get the order of either export to match up.

The script used to list file names and direct links was as follows:

```
    // replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'your-folder';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );

  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Comment: I think that providing your current script for replicating your issue will help users think of your solution. Also, by this, we can also know the language you want to use to resolve your issue.

Comment: As @Tanaike mentioned , you said `I can bulk copy the shareable links` which means you have a script. Please show it to us. Let's see how we can go on with that or to create a new one.

Comment: I have updated the query with more info. Hopefully this helps in understanding my question.

Comment: @Dave Morrison Thank you for replying. 1. You want to use Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? 2. Can I ask you about the issue of your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike the export that this script provides generates a link that is available to me when logged in. I am wanting to generate ‘share’ links so that they can be accessed by others. I am using them as download links on a website where I am selling photography.

Comment: @Dave Morrison Thank you for replying. 1. You want to use Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? 2. You want to create an URL of a file for downloading from users who are not logged in to Google. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tanaike Yes, that is correct. All the files in question are set to ‘view only’ to people with a share link. I would like the output to be in an adjacent column to each file’s name so that I can apply the link to the correct image in my store.

Comment: Have you tried using `getDownloadUrl()` instead of `getUrl()`?

Comment: @Dave Morrison In your situation, in order to make users download the file without the login, the file is required to be shared publicly and the URL is like ``https://drive.google.com/uc?id=###``. How about this?

Comment: @ross I wish that had worked. The links that were output were very different to any google link I have seen and were unuseable.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that is exactly the type of link I want listed beside the file names. I just don't know the command I need to replace 'file.getUrl()' with.

Comment: @Dave Morrison Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. How about modifying from ``link = file.getUrl();`` to ``link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();`` or ``link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + file.getId();``? In your situation, I'm not sure whether ``export=download`` of the query parameter is required. So please confirm this. If you want to make users download the file without the login to Google, please share the file. Also please be careful this.

Comment: @Tanaike Your first suggestion of `link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();` gave exactly the result I wanted! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Dave Morrison Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post the solution as an answer and accept it? By this, other users who has the same issue can see your question and answer as the resolved one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'your-folder';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(['name', 'link']);

  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while (contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();
    sheet.appendRow([name, link]);
  }
};
```