# Names and links to images in multiple folders on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-drive-api

Does anyone know how I can create a google sheet that is within multiple folders on Google Drive with columns of `folder name`, `image name`, and `shareable link to image`?

Using something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453087/can-i-create-a-list-of-images-in-my-google-drive-including-file-name-and-share)

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of the issue of `Using something similar to this`? Or, can I ask you about the difference between `Using something similar to this` and your question?

Comment: @Tanaike this one is great but it only has the file name and link and I need an additional column with the sub-folders that contain these images as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list from the specific folder including the subfolders.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set the top folder ID.

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const getFlieList = (folder, res = []) => {
    const files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      res.push([file.getParents().next().getName(), file.getName(), file.getUrl()]);
    }
    const folders = folder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) getFlieList(folders.next(), res);
    return res;
  }
  const header = ["folder", "name", "URL"];
  const values = [header, ...getFlieList(folder)];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- From `Is there a possibility of only getting the names and links for image files (.jpg) and ignoring other file types?`, in this case, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const files = folder.getFiles();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
    ```

Comment: thanks for this. I followed your instructions above to set things up and the script 'executes' but does not stop and it has been quite a while already. I am also testing it out on a smaller folder with only a handful of images

Comment: @Funkeh-Monkeh Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested my proposed script using a sample folder, the script works. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate `I followed your instructions above to set things up and the script 'executes' but does not stop and it has been quite a while already. I am also testing it out on a smaller folder with only a handful of images`. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the sample situation for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Funkeh-Monkeh From your reply, as another method, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thanks so much, this works now! Is there a possibility of only getting the names and links for image files (.jpg) and ignoring other file types?

Comment: @Funkeh-Monkeh Thank you for replying. About `Is there a possibility of only getting the names and links for image files (.jpg) and ignoring other file types?`, if you want to retrieve only JPEG files, please modify `const files = folder.getFiles();` to `const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);` and test it again.

Comment: Unfortunately, now I get this error and am not sure if there's any way around this - `Error Exceeded maximum execution time`

Comment: @Funkeh-Monkeh About your new question of `Unfortunately, now I get this error and am not sure if there's any way around this - Error Exceeded maximum execution time`, I would like to support you. But, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. When you post it as a new question, please include more information for replicating your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250384/discussion-between-funkeh-monkeh-and-tanaike).